# 2's complement of negative fractional number

Tags: floating-point

I have tried to search it out on google before posting it here but didn't find explained way.My question is as follows:

What is 2's complement representation of -5/8 ?

It would help even if way is provided to get 2's complement of negative fractional no ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

2's compliment can only be used to represent integers.

However, one solution, you could use two 2's compliment values, one to scale the other. For example, to represent -5/8 you could have two variables, containing values (-5, -8) or for simpler arithmetic, (-5, -3) where the -3 represents the number of bit shifts.

Another solution could be to have an implicit shift. For example, you could use a 16 bit, 2's compliment number to represent values from -256 to +255. In that case, the most significant bit would be the sign, the 8 lower bits would be the integer, and the lowest 7 bits would be the fraction.

You could arrange this however you like. You could, for example, just use 8 bits, and have the following bit significance:

- (bit 7) Sign
- (bit 6) 8's
- (bit 5) 4's
- (bit 4) 2's
- (bit 3) 1's
- (bit 2) halves
- (bit 1) quarters
- (bit 0) 8ths

This would give you values in 8th increments, in the following ranges:

Positive: 0 to 15.875
Negative: -0.125 to -16

As per AndrejaKo's comment, this is a fixed point representation.

An example of possible representations using a 4-bit binary number

```
Binary | Regular 2's comp. | /16 2's comp    | /8 2's comp
------ | ----------------- | --------------- | ------------

0000     0                   0      (0)        0
0001     1                   0.0625 (1/16)     0.125 (1/8)
0010     2                   0.125  (2/16)     0.25  (2/8)
0011     3                   0.1875 (3/16)     0.325 (3/8)
0100     4                   0.25   (4/16)     0.5   (4/8)
0101     5                   0.3125 (5/16)     0.625 (5/8)
0110     6                   0.325  (6/16)     0.75  (6/8)
0111     7                   0.4375 (7/16)     0.825 (7/8)

1111     -1                  -0.0625 (-1/16)   -0.125 (1/8)
1110     -2                  -0.125  (-2/16)   -0.25  (-2/8)
1101     -3                  -0.1875 (-3/16)   -0.325 (-3/8)
1100     -4                  -0.25   (-4/16)   -0.5   (-4/8)
1011     -5                  -0.3125 (-5/16)   -0.625 (-5/8)
1010     -6                  -0.325  (-6/16)   -0.75  (-6/8)
1001     -7                  -0.4375 (-7/16)   -0.825 (-7/8)
1000     -8                  -0.5    (-8/16)   -1     (-8/8)
```

As you can see, 1011 represents -5 in two's compliment. So if you have an implicit bit shift of 3, (equivalent to divide by 8), it represents -5/8.

Similarly, if you are using 5 bits, where you have an implicit divide by 16, the bit value would be 10110, where the leading 1 denotes the sign, and 0110 in the context of the 2's compliment signed bit represents 5/8.

So here is where your "0110" comes from:

```
Binary | Reg. 2's comp. | /16 2's comp    
------ | -------------- | --------------- 
11111     -1              -0.0625 (-1/16)
11110     -2              -0.125  (-2/16)
11101     -3              -0.1875 (-3/16)
11100     -4              -0.25   (-4/16)
....
10111     -9              -0.5625 (-9/16)
10110     -10             -0.625  (-10/16) <== where "0110" equals -5/8
10101     -11             -0.6875 (-11/16)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why we wouldn't be able to use two's complement to represent fixed point decimal numbers? Right now, I don't see a reason why that wouldn't work, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Fixed point, yes that would work, as per my answer, if I understand you correctly? So a fixed number of bits could be assigned to fractions of 8ths, 16ths, and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of. So instead of having the right-most bit representing 1, it could represent 1/16.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your answer.we can represent the -5/8 using 2's complement representation.provided answer is .0110.But i don't know how to conclude this.

Comment: By definition, for a negative number represented by 2's compliment, the MSb *must* be a 1. So 0110 cannot represent a negative number. However, if you precede it by a 1, and assume an implicit /16 with a total of 5 bits, 10110 represents -5/8. See my modification to my answer.